# Android overlapping text on adapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

On some phones, mainly a Galaxy S2 I am having an issue where the results in a custom adapter overlap on each other. This is an example where user searched for the word "vaginal" in a search field, it is a medical app.

[image]

I am not sure the best way to describe this and the code is pretty convoluted at this point. The user types in a word, and database results come in showing matches. These results are in a List object and displayed via adapter.
On most phones this works as expected, with results being sequential. On at least one device, the above screenshot happens.

Is this is a known error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Metaphor of what you are asking: "I have an equation that I can't solve, I won't show it to you, but how do I solve it?". Not much we can help with without seeing any code...

Comment: Check your convert view and work on your row xml, keep it in a linear layout with wrap_content parameter, and pass that optimized row UI. You will find solution.

Comment: On the row adapter layout, try setting a max width or max characters to see how it looks like.

Comment: @StevenByle yes, the assumption is that there are only a few ways to do an adapter in android and it works on most devices this way, so maybe there is a known issue about autocompletetextviews and adapters.

Comment: @Puneet , with this many possibilities I feel like I need this exact device to test it on, only one of my testers has it right now

Comment: Do you have this problem when you scroll the list view or when perform search ??

Comment: @Bhupendrasinh when the search has performed and the results have come back, they just appear that way, I believe (I haven't gotten a galaxy s2 to see this error personally yet)

Comment: i have face this problem in different way , that galaxy grand not support my screen view. that might be happen with you for device specific problem . Do you have set cache color listview ???

Comment: Can you share your list layout code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How often can you update a textview without mess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491280/how-often-can-you-update-a-textview-without-mess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks rather like [How often can you update a textview without mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491280/how-often-can-you-update-a-textview-without-mess) , possibly caused by View reuse in the list adapter. The solution to that issue is to force the background to a fully opaque colour.