# Android TextView setText overlays previous Text

Tags: android, textview, settext

I would like to set a Text into a TextView of my app(lication). This is the code I used:

```
TextView lonTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLonWert);
lonTextView.setText(longitude.toString());
```

Actually it works, but the previous Text is still displayed! For example  a 4 overlays an 8 (you cannot read the text any more).

I have a Activity starting a service. Then registering a LocalBroadcastReceiver to the Activity. The service peridically sends location objects to the activity. From the location I get e.g. the longitude and would like to update a textview (just contains the longitude) with the new longitude.

I would be very pleased if anyone has an idea to solve this problem.

UPDATE:
The full code is quite long, so here are the relevant fragments:

TrackingActivity.java

```
public class TrackingActivity extends Activity {

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps; 

public String filename;

/* Um eigene Position anzuzeigen */
ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemArray;
protected MapView mapView;
protected MapController mapController;
public Boolean isPause;
public Boolean isTracking;
public MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
PathOverlay myPath;
List<GeoPoint> path;

public BroadcastReceiver screenReceiver;

/* Textviews setzen */
TextView lonTextView;
TextView latTextView;
TextView altTextView;
TextView accTextView;

// Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_tracking, menu);
    MenuItem mi_startTracking = menu.findItem(R.id.start_tracking);
    mi_startTracking.setVisible(true);
    return true;
}*/

/**
 * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
 * Identify single menu item by it's id
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    ...
}    

@Override

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   ...
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracking);

    isTracking  = false;
    isPause     = false;

    // create GPS-class object
    gps = new GPSTracker(TrackingActivity.this
                        ,null);

    myPath  = new PathOverlay(Color.RED, this);
    path    = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();

   /* Map anzeigen */
    mapView = new MapView(this, 500);
    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    org.osmdroid.views.MapView.LayoutParams mapParams = new                   org.osmdroid.views.MapView.LayoutParams(
            org.osmdroid.views.MapView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            org.osmdroid.views.MapView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            null, 0, 0, 0);
    /*löst Fehler aus: mapView.setClickable(true);*/
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController = new MapController(mapView);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(15);


    //--- Create Overlay
    overlayItemArray = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    DefaultResourceProxyImpl defaultResourceProxyImpl   = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(this);
    MyItemizedIconOverlay myItemizedIconOverlay         = new MyItemizedIconOverlay(
                                                        overlayItemArray, null, defaultResourceProxyImpl);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedIconOverlay);
    //---

    //Add current position
    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

    /* Lege Pfad auf Karte */
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myPath);
    mapView.invalidate();
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.trackingLinearLayoutMap);

    myLayout.addView(mapView,mapParams);

}

private BroadcastReceiver gpsDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Log.d("TrackingActivity", "in Receiver");
        /* alles was der Service liefert */
        String action       = intent.getAction();
        Double altitude     = intent.getDoubleExtra("altitude", 0);
        Double longitude    = intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0);
        Double latitude     = intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0);
        Bundle b            = intent.getExtras();
        Location location   = (Location)b.get("location");

        Log.d("received","Receiver: "+longitude+" ; "+latitude);


        //Log.d("TrackingActivity", "vor GeoPoint");
        GeoPoint locGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);

                /* Erstelle Pfad */
        if(isTracking){
            path.add(locGeoPoint);
            myPath.addPoint(locGeoPoint);
        }
        //Log.d("TrackingActivity", "nach GeoPoint: "+locGeoPoint.toString());
        mapController.setCenter(locGeoPoint);

        setOverlayLoc(location);

        /* Textviews Werte setzen */
        lonTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLonWert);
        lonTextView.setText(longitude.toString());
        //lonTextView.invalidate();

        latTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLatWert);
        latTextView.setText(latitude.toString());
        //latTextView.invalidate();

        altTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAltWert);
        altTextView.setText(altitude.toString());
        //altTextView.invalidate();

        accTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAccWert);
        accTextView.setText(Float.toString(location.getAccuracy())+" m");
        //accTextView.invalidate();

        /* Karte aktualisieren */
        mapView.invalidate();

    }
};
...
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    /* Registriere BroadcastReceiver für GPSDaten */
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(gpsDataReceiver, new IntentFilter("gpsdata"));

        ...

}
...
```

Here my layout .xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/trackingLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/trackingStatusOuterWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="kein GPS Signal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/trackingStautsInnerWrapper2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLonLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Länge: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLonWert"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLatLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Breite: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLatWert"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/trackingStautsInnerWrapper3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAltLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Höhe: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAltWert"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAccLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Genauigkeit: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAccWert"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!--  
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"/>
-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/trackingLinearLayoutMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: can you post you full code & xml ?r

Comment: updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll never believe this, but if you head over to [How often can you update a textview without mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491280/how-often-can-you-update-a-textview-without-mess) you will find a question and answer which I think are addressing the issue.

If these don't resolve the issue, you may need to replace the button with a custom View with the onDraw overridden using `canvas.drawText()` to put the text in place. You can then be sure to wipe any previous history ...

IF you just want a non transparent black background, create (or add to) the colors.xml file in your `res` directory:

```
<resources>
    <color name="black">#ff000000</color>
</resources>
```

and add:

```
    android:background="@color/black"
```

To the xml for the TextView.

Comment: Awesome, that is the same problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's very strange! didn't hear of it ! 
There is another way to check this issue. try removing all other text views inside the linear layout . maybe one of them is overlaying on the other.

Comment: @UdiOshi That is always worth checking, but not the case in the question I'm pointing to ...

Comment: @UdiOshi : I removed all TextViews except one, but the same effect occured.

Comment: I realized now, that the background of the layout is black but I have never defined the backgroundcolor for this layout. Same thing with textcolor - it is white. Are black background and white text color default? Or is it possible, that there are complications with other layout.xml files where linearlayouts with these settings are defined?

Comment: If you define the background to a full alpha colour (eg. black) I would expect it to work fine (as per the question I've linked to). If you want the text to have a transparent background, things are more complex. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to set teh background to black (no transparency - like the code I posted in my question).

Comment: Updated answer to achieve this.

Comment: I still think the best way to do this is dynamically load the Widget by casting its outer Containing View to a ViewGroup. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362360/android-settext-on-a-textview-will-overwrite-previous-text/22362483#22362483

Comment: @inner_class7 Nice solution, hence upvote, next time I face the issue I will compare the different approaches :-)

Comment: @NeilTownsend Thanks, yeah I was pretty happy with the results. This approach gives you a lot more control and you can do this with any widget.. Its just important to note that all child widgets inherit the  layout params of the parent View.

Comment: came here to say I also had this issue, on multiple views inside a layout which got a background resource attribute removed in a commit by my team. By replacing the background again, the problem got fixed. This only seems to happen on 4.4 and below, same issue didn't occur on Lollipop'd devices

Answer (score -2):

The line `android:text=""` in

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewLonWert"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

is redundant, you can remove that line.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question. It would be better as a comment instead.