# android:background="#000000" doesn't work in Android 2.3.6 and below

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Image View in my layout and `android:background` isn't working in Android 2.3.6 and below.
It works perfectly in newer versions.

Here is the code:

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:alpha="0.5"
     android:background="#000000" />
```

It is also inside 2 Frame Layouts but I don't think this will help solving the issue because every child shows perfectly, except this Image View. I'll post the code if you want.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378636/setting-background-colour-of-android-layout-element) and try it..

Comment: Have you tried "#ff000000" to ensure full alpha?

Comment: Ok @ErickFilho and please do tell me the result..

Comment: @NeilTownsend No, I didn't think it could be related to alpha because in my mind, if alpha wasn't supported, it should be ignored and my imageview background shouldn't be affected.

Comment: @ErickFilho Whilst in principle I agree with you, my personal experience with TextViews (eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491280/how-often-can-you-update-a-textview-without-mess/16497426#16497426) has led me to make my code pretty explicit about many "theoretically irrelevant" things with them.

Answer (score 2):

`View.setAlpha` was introduced in API Level 11. You can change also the alpha through the background property. From the doc

> May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or
>   "#aarrggbb".

```
android:background="#7A000000"
```